# Trying to connect Trac 0.12 (privately hosted) with GitHub

Tags: python, git, github, trac

Any ideas on connecting GitHub with a locally hosted Trac 0.12 instance? We were thinking of using GitHub's email service hook to shoot off an email anytime GitHub is pushed to, which would fire off a script to have our local repo pull from GitHub, and also tell Trac to re-sync the repo. Any ideas to improve on what we were thinking? If you need any more background info, let me know. Thanks!

Comment: your question is a bit too general, because we don't know your requirements. But take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/623130/git-and-trac-or-similar, maybe that will help

Answer (score 0):

You should use a webhook, not the email service.

http://help.github.com/post-receive-hooks/

Answer (score 0):

We were trying to avoid opening a port on on our firewall, so we thought an email might be easier than using the post-receive url service hook. If we had a publicly hosted Trac instance, we would definitely go the rout of the post-receive url, but since we are hosted internally, this is not an option.

Comment: This should be written as a comment on Tekkub's answer, not as an answer itself.