# Keeping track of To-Do and issues in Git

Tags: git, version-control, github

I'm a newbie to Git and version control in general.  How do you keep track of their coding to-do list and issues/bugs?

Note that I'm working on a private project (e-commerce website) with just 2 developers.

Comment: This is a poll, not a question.

Comment: I've edited it to say "you" instead of "most".  I just want to know what people do, and get an idea of best practices.

Comment: The question still falls neatly under the [definition of questions not to ask section in the site faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask).

Answer (score 4):

Git is not meant to be a bug tracking system, and if your need are a bit more complex than a simple "TODO" file, then you need to [integrate Git with other systems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/623130/git-and-trac-or-similar).

That being said, I like to put a `README` at the root directory of my repo.
That way, I can have a [quick description of what the branch is for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108405/branch-descriptions-in-git/2108832#2108832).

```
git show myBranch:README
```

Comment: This is excellent because it's simple and it cooperates well with `git diff`, `git blame`, etc.!

Answer (score 2):

I'm also developing standalone/in a small team and not having found anything that would not be complete overkill for my needs I came up with a small script, [Git-Track](https://github.com/dhesse/Git-Track) to keep track of bugs/issues.

I've had some colleges test it and the resonance was positive. We work in science, most projects have only one or two developers and thus any major bug tracking solution is just way too fancy to be really useful.

Answer (score 2):

I'm late to this party but for anyone looking to track TODOs using a github app you can use http://srcoftruth.com. It's a free app that finds the TODOs in your source code on check-in and opens an issue for each found TODO, tracks it over time and closes it when the TODO is removed from the repo.